# curl req1 and rea2 same curl handle for CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT + CURLOPT_TIMEOUT issue ....

Tags: libcurl

curll_handle = Curl init()

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 )
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
```

Request1:(curll_handle)

```
Curl_easy_perform(curll_handle)
For connection = 20 secs
Chal response request = 30 secs
```

request2:same handle used as above

```
curl_slist_append(headers, "Connection: Close");

Curl_easy_perform(curll_handle)
```

Questions:

```
Request 1:
    will it use both timeouts(connection and response timeouts) for curl perform?
    what is the total time will take? as per my understand 30 secs(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT + CURLOPT_TIMEOUT)

Request 2:
    if we use same request1 curl handle for request2. is it(req2) curl_easy_perform() will d0 both connection and response sequence requestS?
    what the timeout value use for sencond request if use same req1 curl handle?
```

Answer (score 0):

Request 1:

`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` is the maximum time for the entire operation. It will not spend more time. You know it will be done within 30 seconds, successful or not.

`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` is the longest time you allow the "connection phase" to take. If the connection to the remote server is not done within 20 seconds, the transfer will return failure.

The times are set totally independent of each other. So if the connection phase takes 19 seconds, there is 11 seconds left for the transfer to complete or the maximum timeout will trigger.

Request 2:

Uses the same options and options are sticky and will be the same until changed, so it will have the exact same timeout values as request 1.

If the connection is kept and re-used from request 1, the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` won't trigger since it is already connected.

Comment: Hi,  As the request-2 uses the persistent connection from the request-1 does really CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT matters in the request-2?

Comment: Right, I amended my answer now to include that detail!