# CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT is not working

Tags: php, http, curl, proxy, libcurl

i am learning about CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, i am using a proxy in this test with 25 seconds timeout setting, but it never timed out, i dont know why. here is my simple code

```
$proxy="124.206.54.251:3128";
$timeout = 25;
$url = "http://google.com";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); 
$headerSent = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ); 
$returned_msg = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$info= curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "<br>".$returned_msg."<br>".$info['total_time']."<br>".$error;
```

can someone plz tell why it never timed out? i only want to wait 25 second and it is unable to for any reason such as proxy is dead, then it should timed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT only sets the timeout for the amount of time it takes to connect.  If you want to limit the amount of time the entire request is allowed to take, use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer, what if i use both CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT together ? will they work ? i want to note time that how many seconds it took to connect and i also want to allow maximum 25 seconds to connect.

Comment: Yep, you can use them together.  Then, if you want to check the time it took to connect, you can grab the connect_time from your $info array.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482680/curl-req1-and-rea2-same-curl-handle-for-curlopt-connecttimeout-curlopt-timeout for similar info